# Can't fetch data from API Closure

Tags: swift, printing, closures

I am a beginner in Swift. I am trying to make app to fetch data from a Django server, but I'm stuck in fetch data from Closure, my code is as below:

```
var datasource: [Vender] = []

override func vieDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 
   loaddata()
   print(datasource) //#1 print
}
 
func loadata(){ 
    VenderAPI(method: "GET", endpoint: "vender", APIportocol: Vender(), index: "") {
    Result in 
      switch Result {
        case .failure(let error):
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        case .success(let APIdata):
          for data in APIdata {
            self.datasource.append(data)
         }
     }
  print(self.datasource) //#2 print
}
```

My question is, I can get #2 print (correct data and format from server), but not #1 print (always empty).
Can somebody help me?  I will so appreciate.

Comment: You are missing the "asynchrone" (concept & keyword). Replace `for data in APIdata { self.datasource.append(data) }`, with `for data in APIdata { self.datasource.append(data) } print("in closure: \(self.datasource)")`, replace `print(self.datasource) //#2 print` with `print("after closure: \(self.datasource)") //#2 print` Which print will appear in console first in your opinion ? What's the reality?

Comment: both of print appear in console

Comment: "both of print appear in console ": In which order? That's the important part, and according to the order, does `datasource` is empty at that moment?

Comment: "In clouse" appears before "after clouse" in console, and datasource(#1 print) still empty at this moment. But I tried 1 second delay before printing datasource, it works!!!

Comment: Thanks you a lot, it’s an async problem. Thanks your hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Larme mentioned, you need to deal with the asynchronous function. Read-up about it.
Try this approach:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loaddata() { done in  // <--- here
        print(datasource) // print when all work is done
    }
}
 
func loadata(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> ()) {  // <--- here
    VenderAPI(method: "GET", endpoint: "vender", APIportocol: Vender(), index: "") {
        result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        case .success(let APIdata):
            for data in APIdata {
                self.datasource.append(data)
            }
        }
        completion(true)  // <--- here
    }
}
```

Comment: it prints successfuly in loaddata() { done in print(datasource)}, but can I get the data in datasource out of the closure?  Actually, I would use datasource to make a TableView, but the content in datasource is still empty out out of the clouse.

Comment: You need to understand how asynchronous functions with completion handler work. 
Search, read, study up on `swift completion handler`. For example: https://medium.com/@dhavalkansara51/completion-handler-in-swift-with-escaping-and-nonescaping-closures-1ea717dc93a4

Comment: Thanks you a lot! After I read the information of completion handler and make some modify (follow your suggestion), it work well in my code.